# Incoming mail loop in Gmail

Tags: loops, gmail

I have an issue I can't resolve - we have a "main" Gmail account, let's say it's called main@gmail.com. Emails from main@gmail.com are redirected to x other accounts, let's say about 10.

Yesterday we received a normal e-mail message on main@gmail.com and it was redirected to the other mentioned accounts. The problem is, every 3 minutes the same exact e-mail is sent again to main@gmail.com and then redirected to other accounts.

Its the endless loop on our side or on the senders side? We contacted the senders side and they say, that the message was sent from their side only once. Any ideas?

Comment: Does any of the x other accounts have an automatic redirect back to main@gmail.com ?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the email headers?

Comment: None of the other accounts have any kind of forwarding/redirect options enabled.

Comment: Yes, but do you suggest to look on something specific?